# If the vectors $v$ and $w$ are known, given $A*v=w$, can you solve for $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm looking for the case where $v$ and $w$ are $6$ dimensional and $A$ is $6$ by $6$, but a general solution for n dimensional vectors and an $n$ by $n$ matrix would be cool to know to.

Other data: $A$ is a permutation matrix, and the entries of $v$ and $w$ are integral.

Comment: In your very specific case of $A$ being a permutation matrix... if the entries of $v$ are all distinct then yes you can find $A$ uniquely.  If the entries of $v$ are *not* all distinct... then no you can not find it uniquely but you can narrow it down.  As for what $A$ would be... it should be obvious by looking at how $v$ and $w$ compare to one another.  Note that the entries of $v$ and of $w$ will be identical but in a possibly different order.  $A$ would describe that changing of order.

Comment: that is exacly what im looking for. so, what calculation do i need to do to solve for A

Comment: Suppose that $v$ has distinct entries.  Suppose without loss of generality that those entries are specifically $1,2,3,4,\dots, n$ in that order.  Consider the transpose of $v$.  Picture that above the transpose of $w$.  This is the permutation $A$ written in [two line notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Two-line_notation)

Comment: but i need it in matrix form, because i will multiply it with other vectors to preform the permutation

Comment: Permutations are very well known.  You should be able to read enough about how permutations are displayed and formatted in their various representations to know how to get what you want out of this.  Play with it a bit more... I'm sure you can do it.  "*If the number in the ____'th position of vector $v$ got moved to the ____'th position of vector $w$, then write a $1$ in the ____'th row ____'th column of $A$*"

Answer (score 1):

In a $n-$dimensional vector space a matrix is determined by the image of $n$ linearly independent vectors. If $m<n$ and you assign $A\cdot v_i$, $i=1,...,m$ there are different matrices $A,A'$ with the same results on the $v_i$. Their difference has a kernel containing the span of the $v_i$.